# xlwings(0.7.0) importing UDF error

Tags: udf, xlwings

[image: Error]

Hello,

My problem is that when i try to import an UDF in Ecxel 2013 I receive the error message can be seen on the picture. I have installed xlwings and it works except the UDF importing. Note that i used "xlwings quickstart myproject" so there is no problem with the file names and i also used the sample function so that should be fine as well

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently don't understand *why* you get that error, but I should be able to tell you how you can work around it for now:

Open the file `udfs.py` in the xlwings package and remove the last argument on line 36, i.e. remove `, ArgumentDescriptions=argdocs`.

The intended functionality of that line (showing function argument description) is currently broken anyway (see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/367)) so hopefully this will be resolved in a future version.

Comment: It removed the error message but  the imported function does not work. It throws a compile error: Ambiguous name detected: Py

Comment: Hello, It is working now! It seems that all i had to do is to upgrade py(from 1.4.26 to 1.4.31) and install Ipython

Comment: @user3617153 is it working now with this fix or would it also work without the fix?

Comment: It only works with the fix. I got the original error message without it.